# Rails Application: Typeahead append suggestions to content in textarea

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

This is my first post here in the community, so I would greatly appreciate if you could give me some advice on my problem I'm facing with **twitter-typeahead** in a Rails application.

I'm working on a web application where a twitter clone is integrated, allowing users to write posts which can have hashtags in them. When writing the post, I would like to give the user suggestions which existings hashtags from the database he or she could use.

Json with suggestions is correctly provided at the specified url */autocomplete/hashtags?query=%QUERY* and I get suggestions while typing which I can choose from. The problem is that every time I select one suggestion, the complete text in the text_area field gets deleted and replaced by the selected hashtag. How can I **append** the chosen selection to the existing text?

E.g. when I type

> This is a new #has

and select #hashtag as the suggested hashtag, I want the content of the text_area to be:

> This is a new #hashtag

Best
Sebastian

**hashtags.js**

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

  var hashtags = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('tag'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    remote: {
      url: '/autocomplete/hashtags?query=%QUERY',
      wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
  });

    hashtags.initialize();

    $('.typeahead-hashtags').typeahead(null, {
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      name: 'hashtags',
      displayKey: 'tag',
      source: hashtags.ttAdapter(),
    });
  }

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

**_micropost_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@micropost, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'typeahead-hashtags form-control col-md-6' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```